# Could not perform immediate configuration on 'perl'

Tags: linux, debian, perl, aptitude, apt-get

I'm trying to upgrade a debian squeeze system to wheezy.
I've done an apt-get update && apt-get -V upgrade on squeeze, then changed my source.list to reference wheezy not squeeze.

then, apt-get update (works fine)

then,

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

or

```
aptitude full-upgrade
```

no matter what I try the dist-upgrade fails with the message

```
Could not perform immediate configuration on 'perl'
```

for good measure i've also tried

```
apt-get install perl -o APT::Immediate-Configure=0
```

which some bug reports mention working, but it doesn't work for me.

I've found no way to upgrade from squeeze to wheezy without the upgrade failing because of this error using either apt-get or aptitude.

Does anyone know of a work around or fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=639290), a possible workaround would be to first update `apt` itself and then run the `dist-upgrade`.

So, first point your sources to `wheezy`, then run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade apt
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

---

As per the OP's request, I am including the solution he found in the bug report linked to above:

You need to first add experimental to sources.list `deb ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian experimental main` and then do

```
aptitude install apt from experimental"
```

It must be `aptitude`, `apt-get` failed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip however it didn't work for me.  I get the same error.

Comment: @mark oh, did you have a look through the bug report I linked to? Another possibility would be to simply remove `perl`, then upgrade and then reinstall it. Make sure to only remove the `perl` package and not `perl-base` which is needed.

Comment: Yes i did, and I've found it.  You need to first add experimental to sources.list (deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian experimental main) and then do "aptitude install apt from experimental" (must be aptitude, apt-get failed).  then it works (for me). So thanks hugely, if you update your answer with the above I'll accept it.

Comment: @mark glad you sorted it out, I've added your solution to my answer.